# The text in the bootstrap card is not showed completely/properly

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, horizontal-scrolling

I have a row of bootstrap cards, but the '.card-text' is not displayed properly. I tried giving more space to '.card-text' to let it display correctly but nothing is changing. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stackoverflow/1/css.css"/>
           <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<div id="skills_container">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/html.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">HTML</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Basic and complex HTML tags for different uses.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/css.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">CSS</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Knowledge in CSS displays, Responsive design and animations</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/cambridge.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">B1 Cambridge English</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Cambridge B1 Degree English Level.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/js.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Javascript Client Basics</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Basic usage of js in client</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/python.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Python Basics</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Knowledge in basic uses of python</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/marketing.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Analytics and Markeing</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Analytics and Digital Marketing knowledge.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
#skills_container{
    width:96vw;
    display:flex;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:1rem;
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius:1rem;
  }
  
  .card{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 2px;
  }
  
  /* .card-text{
    
  } */
```

**If you like to, you can directly go to the hosted site on: https://paucabrera.com/stackoverflow/1/**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```css
#skills_container{
    width:96vw;
    display:flex;
    overflow-y: hidden;
    overflow-x:auto;
    white-space:nowrap;
    padding:1rem;
    border:1px solid;
    border-radius:1rem;
  }
  
  .card{
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 2px;
  }
  
.card-body{
        white-space: normal;
  }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
           <link rel="stylesheet" href="/stackoverflow/1/css.css"/>
           <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-1BmE4kWBq78iYhFldvKuhfTAU6auU8tT94WrHftjDbrCEXSU1oBoqyl2QvZ6jIW3" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

<div id="skills_container">
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/html.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">HTML</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Basic and complex HTML tags for different uses.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/css.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">CSS</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Knowledge in CSS displays, Responsive design and animations</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/cambridge.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">B1 Cambridge English</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Cambridge B1 Degree English Level.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/js.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Javascript Client Basics</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Basic usage of js in client</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/python.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Python Basics</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Knowledge in basic uses of python</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
                      <img src="/img/fotos-index/optimizadas/marketing.webp" class="card-img-top" alt="...">
                      <div class="card-body">
                        <h5 class="card-title">Analytics and Markeing</h5>
                        <p class="card-text">Analytics and Digital Marketing knowledge.</p>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>

</body>
</html>
```